# Appending " results in appending of " 2 times

Tags: python, string-concatenation

Trying to convert given text file to `.json` file using a python script.
I am trying to append double quotes as: `output_str = '"'+input_str+'"'` but it results in double quotes twice in the output.

```
i.e. if input_str = row
output_str = ""row"" instead of "row"
row.append(str)
writer = csv.writer(open("data.json",'wb'), delimiter=',')
writer.write(row)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is confusing. You are outputting to JSON and you want double quotes or you don't want double quotes? Could you post your code with your question, please?

Comment: For an explanation of why code is required here, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://SSCCE.ORG

Comment: Are you sure that `input_str` doesn’t already contain the double quotes? Because it looks like it does.

Comment: @poke Thats what I was thinking.

Comment: Are you looking at your output string in JSON already? Cause JSON should have double quotes around string, may be your encoder does it for you.

Comment: FWIW, [this program](http://ideone.com/B2cgPd) will "*convert given text file to .json file using a python script*".

Answer (score 1):

First of all your method seems fine. Second, I would use the `json` library to create json files:

```
import json
a = "this is a test"
json.dumps({"a": a})
>> '{"a": "this is a test"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct actually. Python may add quotes around the string itself, because it's the representation of the `string` object. But these quotes are just add when you display the string in the console, they don't exist otherwise!

```
>>> foo = "foobar"
>>> foo
'foobar'
^      ^
# quotes add via displayed by str() method of foo
>>> '"%s"' % foo
'"foobar"'
```

Comment: Then, by your logic, '#' + foo + '#' should be equal to '#"foo"'. Quotes are added just for output, they are part of repr of string, not of the string itself.

Comment: Yep, I have add more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Some code sample from the shell would be better, but you probably are seeing the shell quote around the string quote.

I recommend using the [json library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to automatically converting your dictionaries to a json file. It will take care of everything for you.